# Pyinstaller exe file is not working/opening

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I am having a tough time overcoming this error, I have searched everywhere for that error message and nothing seems relevant to my situation:

`failed to execute script main`

Here **main** is my Flappy bird game that i made.

I ran `pip install pyinstaller` in the terminal provided in pycharm and after installing finished

I ran `pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole`

After everything finished i opened the dist folder and put my assets file into into as i saw in the tutorial i was referencing form

after doing all this the persons file worked and he was able to run his game but i got the error mentioned above

Im using python 3 and the OS is win 10

any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

[you can see that i have the assets folder their too but am still getting an error]

Comment: Remove the `--noconsole` from your PyInstaller command and regenerate the executable then put the full error log here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the `os`, `sys` or `re` module then you will need to install `pywin32` module(only if you are on `WINDOWS`) to give your program os permissions.

https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

It would be better if you can include your program code in your question.